# Hover over action not working on all elements in Div tag

Tags: html, css, hover

Good afternoon,

I'm struggling to get my hover over box to change the color of the `<a>` tag and change the `<img>` tag.

However, The `<p>` tag does change when I hover over it.

I have inserted all of them under one parent `div` tag.

Is there a way to make this work?

Cheers,
Anrich Vigus

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, We cannot help you if you do not provide any code, can you please put your code

Comment: we cannot guess by your question, you have to **post some bit of your code** for solving a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.divClassOrId:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't understand it, you want to define a feature for a label. For this you need to do operations from css. I'll throw you a sample code like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
div{
    background-color: green;
    width : 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
        <h3>Hello World</h3>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to hover a div and highlight just another one:

HTML:

```
<div class="class">
    <div class="childClass">Test</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.class:hover + .childClass {
    background-color: blue;
}

.childClass {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This will Modify the Child if the parent is hovered

Alternatively you can use:

```
.class:hover ~ childClass {
    backgroud-color: blue;
}
```